# Storing direction/heading information of a vehicle

Tags: mysql, google-maps, dictionary, gps

I am developing a GPS related system. I need to store longitude, latitude and the direction of the vehicle position. According to my understanding the direction is a numeric value. Later I need to identify other vehicles driving on same direction. Let's say heading to north on given road. What is the best way to store the direction. If I store this as a number (60 degree, etc) It will be quite hard to get other vehicles travelling on same direction since that numeric value could be changed slightly. Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: The direction in which vehicles travel along any given road is binary: it's either one way, or it's the other.  You could, for example, represent the direction travelled by vehicles heading toward the northernmost end of a road with a `0` and those heading toward the southernmost end with a `1` (where a road lies more East-West than North-South, you might choose to use those compass points instead).

Comment: @eggyal Thank you so much for your idea. Even I think it could work. I will do some research on that.

Comment: Silly me, better to represent the direction in which the vehicle is travelling by some coding of the end-point.  For example, if I am heading toward `A` on a road that goes from `A` to `B`, my direction is `A`.  That might be the coordinates of `A`, its name, its postal code, or any other encoding provided that it's unique.